# 100 moves for a rook in a two by two board

Tags: mathematics, chess

A rook is in a corner of a two by two board and wants to get to the opposite corner in 100 moves. In how many ways can the rook perform this?

[image]

**Note**: The rook may go through the opposite corner before the 100 moves, but needs to be at the opposite corner at move 100.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are

> 2^99 ways.
>
>  Each move, the rook switches colors. Each time, it can make two different moves. That is the case for the first 99 moves.
>
>  After move 99, the rook will be on a white square. To specifically get to top right, there will be only one move.
>
>
>  Addendum: OP added the clarification that the rook might pass through the top right before the 100 moves. My answer considered that as a given. But what if Rook could NOT go there? From the 99 moves mentioned, the 49 are white->black moves. These would not have two choices anymore, but one, so the final result would change to 2^50.